# Curl on PHP - Get input value

Tags: php, curl

I use curl for get HTML code of url.

```
$loli = 'my_url';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loli);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Test');
$resultat = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

But, when I `echo $resultat`, the value of input don't display.

My URL is a web page with multiple forms ()
There is already pre-filled data in the input.

But curl does not get the value of these forms. How to do ?

Thanks !

Comment: Use http://php.net/curl_error and http://php.net/curl_getinfo to figure out why.

Comment: If the data is populated by Javascript, then this won't happen in the page your fetching.